# Proliant ML350p Gen8 Raid Extending

Tags: raid, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I am assisting in adding 2 more 480 GB SAS drives to a Proliant ML350p Gen8 RAID 5 that currently has 3 drives.  I already know that in my setup, I need to restart the server, press F5 to go into the Array Configuration Utility.  I see on the HP configuration instructions that it will take 15 minutes per gigabyte to extend the RAID.  My question is, after the configuration change is made, can the server be started?  Otherwise if I need to sit at the Configuration Utility screen for 240 hours before the server can resume operation, that will definitely be an impossible task.

Comment: Man, I should write more... but this can be done entirely online without a reboot. I'll post more later.

Comment: Thanks, your help will be appreciated.  From what I can tell, I cannot do it online because the server does not have a cache battery backup, or something like that.  From what I can tell, I have to restart.

Comment: You should get a cache battery/BBWC/FBWC installed.

Comment: I know it can be done online with a battery.  I am looking to see if it is done without a battery and the server shut down, can the server be started and resume normal operation and the expansion work in the background.

Comment: No. Get a battery/flash unit. Running hardware RAID without one is a waste because of the negative performance implications.

Comment: Alright.  I'll get them to spring for a battery and memory.  It's not my money.  Thanks.